# Ubuntu doesn't recognise FairPhone/Android anymore through USB connection

Tags: usb, android

Very similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518479/ubuntu-doesnt-recognize-android-devices-anymore), but different:

Previously, as I connected my FairPhone to my laptop (which now has Ubuntu 14.04 installed), Nautilus popped up showing the root folder of my phone. Now, however, nothing happens and it is not appearing when I go to /media/USER.

Connecting and disconnection makes these differences visible:

- upon connection, a 'drive' becomes visible in the 'disks' window of Ubuntu. Under volumes it sais 'no medium'
- upon connection, the following line becomes available as `lsusb` output: `Bus 003 Device 016: ID 0bb4:0c03 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)` (where the device number increases with one, every time I replug the device)
- running `adb devices` returns `????????????   no permissions`

The weird thing is, that if I select 'MTP connection' on Android, I do get Nautilus popping up and I can watch all files (except the mp4 files concerned - but I can copy the folders and the mp4 files will be copied as well). Plus, as said, it did work before.

Any clue on how to re-enable Ubuntu to recognise Android again?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (which is why I ended up on this thread). My android device was no longer recognize by my computer, when plugged it was merely charging. I checked 'disks' as well and had a similar issue than described previously, and sometimes my device was not even listed. I didn't check the two other points described above but the problem may very well be identical. In my case it simply was a USB cable problem. When I randomly plugged my device with another cable the problem disappeared.