# My desktop doesn't see my android phone

Tags: usb, android, phone

What is my problem is, I am using ubuntu on my laptop and desktop. And I needed to connect my samsung galaxy a30. For connect my laptop I needed to add a rule to " **`/etc/udev/rules.d`**" called "**`51-android.rules`**" which is contain '**`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`**'
this code. And it's worked on my laptop but not in my desktop. I did same steps in my desktop. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm whether this issue is occuring only with your samsung devices.
If yes, simply unlock your phone lockscreen once after connecting usb and the issue would be solved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work. What happening is my phone only charging on my desktop. But I can access everything while I use it from my laptop,

Answer (score 0):

I was meeting a familiar problem with you which said, "other phones work on this machine or this phone works on another machine".

I finally fixed it referring to this link:
https://askubuntu.com/a/845905/1262550

Maybe it can help you, or you can just glance at other answers. Who knows. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the page I used when I connect to my laptop. The problem is I did the same thing on my desktop but it didn't work.